# Export database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, export

I recently created an Ubuntu Virtual Machine in VirtualBox to create a new project.
So now I created  my database in phpmyadmin and I wanted to export my database to keep the data.
The thing is that when I try to export it it throws an error that says that the database couldnt be exported because the origin file couldnt be read.
It may be a php configuration problem (php.ini)? or maybe I created the virtual machine on a wrong way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For security, if you want to save a database, do a dump on the server directly.
You can take a look to this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb

phpmyadmin is good to have something more visual for an human and manage some little changes. But it's not enough secure to be publish on internet. Becareful about that.